# Usage of "to have something done"

Tags: grammar

I received the following message and I was confused.

"Will you be free to have the ABC meeting rescheduled to Monday?"

Which is the correct interpretation of the question,
- the speaker ask me if I can reschedule the meeting to Monday? or
- the speaker ask me if I am available on Monday to attend the meeting?

I wonder if the question was ambiguous?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As an AE speaker, I find that a very odd way to write.

Nevertheless, it means "are you free monday if we reschedule the ABC meeting to then"

Comment: Yes… that's at best a silly way to say *Is it OK for/by you if the ABC meeting is rescheduled to Monday?*